# 1991 Mazda Navajo clutch issue

Tags: ford, manual-transmission

I have a 1991 Mazda Navajo SUV I just purchased, it has a 5 speed manual transmission with 4wd but the 4wd to my knowledge does not work.

I drove it around the first few days I had it and it drove fine except for the whining I kept hearing from the tranny in certain gears. Went to drive it the other day and noticed after putting it in gear and letting off the clutch, it did not move, and along with that it hardly wants to go in gear, and once I do get it in gear and let off the clutch the motor keeps running as if it was in neutral.

Am I in need of a new tranny, clutch or throw out bearing?